# Performance issues when adding NSViews to ScreenSaver view

Tags: macos, screensaver

I'm trying a basic experiment where I add a grid of squares to a macOS ScreenSaver view (created through the Xcode template). I am running on a reasonably well performing MacBook Pro, but for some reason, adding my grid (composed of ~900 `NSView` objects) completely locks up my system — the screen saver hangs.

This isn't an unreasonable amount of views, surely? What's interesting is, I've tried the exact same layout in a macOS app (drawing in its `NSWindow`), and the performance is totally fine.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was causing the performance problem was that all the views were layer-backed. Once I stopped requesting the view to have a layer, performance improved dramatically.

I also went so far to use `CAShapeLayer` instead for improved animation performance.